# Scaling Background for IE 7

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I need to create a scaling background and must be backward compatible for IE 7 :( . Is there a jQuery code I can use to create a scaling background for IE 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to know about full-screen backgrounds:

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: +1 for CSS-Tricks.  I was gonna post this exact link.  jQuery example is what OP would want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about a CSS gradient, check out http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/. Tons of options in that generator, including "IE-safe".